# Data is not displaying in Vue.js 3 template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

My backend data is retrieved nicely but is not displaying in Vue template. My data is showing like this in the console:

```text
Proxy { <target>: (3) […], <handler>: {…} }
​
<target>: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { id: 3, user_id_as_sender: 5, user_id_as_receiver: 4, … }
​​
1: Object { id: 2, user_id_as_sender: 5, user_id_as_receiver: 4, … }
​​
2: Object { id: 1, user_id_as_sender: 5, user_id_as_receiver: 4, … }
​​
length: 3
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
<handler>: Object { _isReadonly: false, _shallow: false }
```

This is my code:

```html
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive" v-if="pinboards">
                    <table class="table table-head-custom table-vertical-center mt-5 mb-5">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>    
                            <th>{{trans('custom.name')}}</th>
                            <th>{{trans('custom.time')}} </th>
                            <th>{{trans('custom.date')}}</th>
                            <th v-if="userId == 'HumanResource' || userId == 'dispatcher'"  class="text-center">{{trans('custom.read')}}</th>
                            <th class="text-right">{{trans('custom.action')}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="(document, index) in pinboards" :class="((document.user_id_as_receiver).split(',')).includes(String(current_user_id)) && !((document.is_read_by_receiver).split(',')).includes(String(current_user_id)) ? 'active' : ''" :key="index">
                                <td >
                                    <a href="" @click.prevent="readMessage(index, document.id)">
                                        <template v-if="document.is_grouped_msg">{{translateDocumentName(document.subject)}}</template>
                                        <template v-else>{{document.user_name}} {{document.user_surname}}</template>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td >{{document.updated_at | formatHours}}</td>
                                <td >{{document.updated_at | formatDate}}</td>
                                <td v-if="userId == 'HumanResource' || userId == 'dispatcher'" class="text-center">
                                    <template v-if="!document.is_grouped_msg">
                                        <i v-if="document.is_read_by_receiver != 0" class="la la-check-double text-success"></i>
                                        <i v-else class="la la-check-double"></i>
                                    </template>
                                    <template v-else>
                                        {{(((document.is_read_by_receiver).split(',')).length)-1}} / {{((document.user_id_as_receiver).split(',')).length}}
                                    </template>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <a @click.prevent="readMessage(index, document.id)" href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-clean delete" title="read">
                                        <i class="la la-eye"></i> {{trans('custom.read')}}
                                    </a>
                                    <a @click.prevent="removeMessage(index, document.id, 'single')" href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-clean delete" title="Delete">
                                        <i class="la la-trash"></i> {{trans('custom.delete')}}
                                    </a>
                                    <a v-if="current_user_id == document.user_id_as_sender" @click.prevent="removeMessage(index, document.id, 'all')" href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-clean delete" title="Delete from all">
                                        <i class="la la-trash"></i> {{trans('custom.deleteFromAll')}}
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <p class="text-center" v-else>{{trans('custom.noPinboard')}}</p>
            </div>
```

```js
            getPinboards() 
            {
                let that = this;

                const url = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                const column_id = url.get("column_id");
                const user_id = url.get("u_id");
                
                if (column_id && user_id) {
                    axios.get(`/get-pinboard/${column_id}/${user_id}`)
                        .then(function(response){
                            if(response.data.success){
                                that.pinboards = response.data.pinboards;
                            }else{
                                toastr.error("Error getting pinboards!");
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    axios.get('/get-pinboard')
                        .then(function(response){
                            if(response.data.success){
                                that.pinboards = response.data.pinboards;
                                console.log(that.pinboards);

                            }else{
                                toastr.error("Error getting pinboards!");
                            }
                        });
                }
            },
```

Comment: Define "not displaying"? What does the page look like? What does the DOM look like?

Comment: Are any errors logged?

Comment: Are you using Options API (it looks like it) or Composition API?

Comment: no error in logged ? and i am not using Composition Api .

Comment: data() 
        {
            return{
                pinboards:[],
                users: [],
                current_user_id: 0,
                form: {
                    selected_users: '',
                    message: '',
                    sender_type: this.userId,
                    attachment: ''
                },
                loader: false,
                messages: [],
            }
        },
        props: ['type', 'lang', 'userId'],
        mounted()
        {
            this.getUsers();
            this.getPinboards();
        },